# Открытие новых окон с помощью QPushButton

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня есть одно окно. С кнопками `окно 1` и `окно 2`. 
При нажатии кнопки "окно 1" должно открываться окно с надписью "Окно 1", 
так же при нажатии кнопки "окно 2" должно открываться окно с надписью "Окно 2".

Я пробовал это сделать, но ничего не получилось

Главное окно (**main.py**):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1081, 455)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 140, 241, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 140, 241, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "2 Окна"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОКНО 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОКНО 2"))
```

Файл для открытия main.py (**mainopen.py**), там же и код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main import Ui_MainWindow

from main1open import Windowone  

from main2open import Windowtwo


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)     #открытие окна вывода

        self.exampleApp = Windowone()   

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     #открытие окна вывода

        self.exampleApp = Windowtwo()   



    def onClicked(self):
            self.exampleApp.show()                  # + показать новое окно пополнения


    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())       

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp.show()                  # + показать новое окно пополнения


    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())       


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**oknomain1.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(366, 478)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 161, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОКНО 1"))
```

**main1open.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from oknomain1 import Ui_MainWindow

class Windowone(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**oknomain2.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(366, 478)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 20, 161, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОКНО 2"))
```

**main2open.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from oknomain2 import Ui_MainWindow

class Windowtwo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете экземпляры для двух окон с одним именем `exampleApp`.

И в модуле `oknomain2.py` - подправьте вместо "**1**" -> "**2**" `MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from main1open import Windowone  
from main2open import Windowtwo

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from main import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1081, 455)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 140, 241, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 140, 241, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "2 Окна"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОКНО 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОКНО 2"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)        
        self.exampleApp = Windowone()   

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.onClicked1)     
        self.exampleApp_2 = Windowtwo()                         # exampleApp_2

    def onClicked(self):
            self.exampleApp.show()                  

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())       

    def onClicked1(self):
            self.exampleApp_2.show()                             # exampleApp_2

    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())       


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]